# When Facebook ads app install measure charge for service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk, facebook-ads-api

I want to tack number of app install via Facebook ads app install. I have completed all the steps.

1. Installed the latest SDK for iOS or Android. Added code in AppDelegate.
2. Registered your app with Facebook.
3. Completed App Settings Page.
4. Completed App Detail Page.

I have selected bidding option as "Cost per Action (CPA)". Now i have some questions on when facebook ads app install will charge ??

1) Does facebook charge to display the Ads if i have selected bidding option as CPA ?? 
 
2) OR It will charge only when if i click on the ad and until i install the app in device and open the app??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it it not a programming question

Comment: @Igy Obviously this is programming question. I want to track the number of app install count via Mobile App Install Ads and for that we need to follow the steps provided by Facebook including programming in the application.

Comment: If you're asking about using Facebook's ads products and how things are billed this is not the right place - there's documentation here for how to set up install tracking: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads#advanced and for other ads questions you can use the help center in Facebook's ads tools

Comment: Any new updates , I've made about 5K paid installs through facebook. Still can't use CPA bid.

Answer (score 0):

For CPA, I think Facebook only charges when there's an "action" actually happening, and in this case, it only charge when an install occurs. Neither impression or clicks on the ad won't charge anything in my perspective.